# Trying to implement CLLocationManager: Getting compile time error

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to implement a `CLLocationManager` into my app and I'm getting the following compile time error.

Code in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
```

Errors:

```
_OBJ_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager," referenced from Obj-c-class-ref in AboutLocationViewController.o

_kCLLocationAccuracyBest," referenced from:
-[AboutLocationViewController viewDidLoad] in AboutLocationViewController.o

Symbol(s)not found for architecture arm7
Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have not added the CoreLocation.framework inside the Frameworks folder. As a result the linker can't find the CLLocationManager class.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.